# Hyperledger Fabric: is there a way to prevent a member of an organization to access a specific smart contract within a chaincode on a channel?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, smartcontracts, hyperledger-chaincode

Suppose I have two organizations on the same channel, A and B, and a chaincode including these methods:

- queryA;
- queryB (that returns a different set of data as output than queryA);
- create;
- update;
- submitNewData.

How can I restrict access of the single methods so that, for example, a member of A can only access create, update and queryA; a member of B can only access submitNewData and queryB. So, a member of A can create the asset and modify a subset of fields (with "update"), a member of B can only modify another subset of fields (according to "submitNewData) and cannot create the asset.

If a peer of B executes a "peer chaincode invoke" to create or queryA, the access is denied.

Should I use ACLs? But how can I refer to the specific smart contract inside the chaincode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You begin talking about a "member", but later you talk about a "peer".

You cannot restrict operations per peer. Every peer joined to the channel with the chaincode installed must proceed in the same way, so that the chaincode works in a deterministic way.

But you can, of course, restrict operations for the requestor, by evaluating its user ID, MSP ID, certificate attributes or whatever you want. For instance, in Go chaincodes, it is usually evaluated in `BeforeTransaction` function:

```golang
type SmartContract struct {
    contractapi.Contract
}

func checkACL(ctx contractapi.TransactionContextInterface) error {
    // Read incoming data from stub
    stub := ctx.GetStub()

    // Extract operation name
    operation, parameters := stub.GetFunctionAndParameters()
    operationSplitted := strings.Split(operation, ":")
    operationName := operationSplitted[len(operationSplitted)-1]

    // Get requestor info from stub
    mspID, err := cid.GetMSPID(stub)
    userID, err := cid.GetID(stub)
    value, found, err := cid.GetAttributeValue(stub, "role")

    // Evaluate your ACLs by contrasting the operation and the requestor your own way
    // ...

    // Return error when disallowed

    // Operation allowed
    return nil
}

func BeforeTransaction(ctx contractapi.TransactionContextInterface) error {
    return checkACL(ctx)
}

func NewSmartContract() *SmartContract {
    sc := new(SmartContract)
    sc.BeforeTransaction = BeforeTransaction
    // ...
    return sc
}
```

Comment: Basically, I want to allow or disallow a smart contract to do the processing (and then generate the corresponding transaction) based on the organization (or consortium) of the one who invokes it. And I think doing this in the smart contract itself like you said is the simplest way to do it.

Comment: Yes. You can define a `BeforeTransaction` function per contract and evaluate `mspID`. I think you can also define one only `BeforeTransaction` function and evaluate `operationSplitted[0]` (If I remember correctly, it may be the contract name). Your ACL conditions may be Go maps or you can even save them in the world state.

Comment: In Java, it's sufficient to override the `beforeTransaction` method of the interface `ContractInterface` that is implemented by the custom contract, right?
I've tried to do so, but it seems that that handler is not invoked.

Comment: It should be sufficient... https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-chaincode-java/release-2.2/api/org/hyperledger/fabric/contract/ContractInterface.html#beforeTransaction(org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.Context)